# What is the iOS equivalent of Android's colors.xml

Tags: ios, colors, resources

In android there is an XML file as `res/values/colors.xml` that lets you organize all of your colors used in your app. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#e60012</color>
  <color name="blue">#33b5e5</color>
  ...
</resources>
```

Is there something like this in iOS? If not, what is the best way to organize colors that are used throughout the app?

I would like to ultimately be able to replace things like `[UIColor greenColor]` with `[MyColor greenColor]`.

Comment: What do you mean by colors throughout the app? You mean the general buttons, etc. colors?

Comment: Yes colors of backgrounds, text, buttons, etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not come across a default file like this. You could create your own custom .plist file which holds the values and you load that when the app starts. Another option is to create a Category for `UIColor` which has a bunch of class methods returning the colors you want.

You could create something that looks like this:

`UIColor+CustomColors.h`:

```
@interface UIColor (CustomColors)

    + (UIColor *)customColor1;
    + (UIColor *)customColor2;
    ...

@end
```

`UIColor+CustomColors.m`:

```
#import "UIColor+CustomColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (CustomColors)

    + (UIColor *)customColor1 {
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
    }
    + (UIColor *)customColor2 {
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.5f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
    ...

@end
```

Then where you set the background you could have something like this:

`ViewController.m`:

```
#import "UIColor+CustomColors.h"

...

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor1];
```

Comment: "Another option is to create a Category of UIColor which has a bunch of class methods returning the colors you want" That sounds like what I want. I am pretty new to Obj C, could you give a small example?

Answer (score 14):

Better later than never...

For Swift:

Create a new class: MyColors.swift that is an extension of UIColor class:

```
extension UIColor{

    static func color1() -> UIColor{

        return Utils.UIColorFromRGB(0x333333)
    }

    static func color2() -> UIColor{

        return Utils.UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff)
    }
}
```

Having in another class (maybe Utils.swift) this func:

```
class func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

You can use it like this <strike>(note the brackets after UIColor)</strike>:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.color1()
```

> *Edit:*
>   Changed the functions to static so that the colors can be used like the normal iOS colors without creating an instance of UIColor.

Answer (score 6):

As of Xcode 9 you can define colors in Asset Catalogs:

Create or use an existing Asset Catalog and click on the plus button on the bottom left of the editor and select "New Color Set":

[image]

You will see a new color called, "Color."

Click on it, then click to show the attributes inspector:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here you can define your color and a lot of other options.

Double click on the name to change the name of the color.

[image]

Design tools like Sketch and Zeplin will allow you to export colors from your design strait into color assets for Xcode:

https://blog.zeplin.io/asset-catalog-colors-on-xcode-9-c4fdccc0381a

Comment: Damn it took Apple 4 or more years just to introduce a simple color file for a project