# iOS equivalent to androids colors.xml

Tags: android, ios, xml, xcode

I'm developing an app with different brandings that do share the same codebase for most parts. In my android project, I got a xml file for every branding containing the colors. Every view used the color codes defined within these xml files instead of using 'hard coded' color codes.

I would like to achieve the same thing within iOS. How can I do this? I would prefer a solution that does not involve dragging all references into the view controller and set colors via code. Is this possible with Xcode?

Comment: Excuse me, but why the downvotes? Explaining what is wrong with this question might help me not repeating the errors I did in your oppinion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187432/what-is-the-ios-equivalent-of-androids-colors-xml/28723206#28723206

Answer (score 0):

Please click on a view and check for Background.Click on dropdown and check 
[image] other... is present , click on that now follow the screenshot attached.

Comment: But as far as I can see this just picks a fix color instead of reading the color from a file. Or would it be possible to read from a file there? Sadly I have only access to xcode in a few days.

Comment: In the picture Hex Color is written , there you can set the hex color code. Otherwise you can set NSObject class objects as colors and set it as background